# Rvest html_table error - Error in out[j + k, ] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm getting an error message that I can't make sense of. My code:

```
 url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Legislature,_2017%E2%80%9318_session"

leg <- read_html(url)

testdata <- leg %>% 
  html_nodes('table') %>% 
  .[6] %>% 
  html_table()
```

To which I get the response:

> Error in out[j + k, ] : subscript out of bounds

When I swap out html_table with html_text I don't get the error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's something weird going on here; I get the same error for a lot of selectors that appear to work fine until the nodes are passed to `html_table`, e.g. `leg %>% html_nodes('h3 + .wikitable') %>% html_table()`

Comment: @alistaire: the code in `html_table()` isn't handling the `colspan` logic right. It's def an `rvest` bug.

Comment: Found this problem. Can confirm it's related to colspan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(htmltab)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Legislature,_2017%E2%80%9318_session"
url %>%
  htmltab(6, rm_nodata_cols = F) %>%
  .[,-1] %>%
  replace_na(list(Notes = "", "Term-limited?" = "")) %>%
  `rownames<-` (seq_len(nrow(.)))
```

Output is:

```
  District              Name      Party       Residence Term-limited? Notes
1        1        Ted Gaines Republican El Dorado Hills                    
2        2      Mike McGuire Democratic      Healdsburg                    
3        3         Bill Dodd Democratic            Napa                    
4        4       Jim Nielsen Republican          Gerber                    
5        5 Cathleen Galgiani Democratic        Stockton                    
6        6       Richard Pan Democratic      Sacramento                    
...
```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you! I don't know what's up with rvest::html_table, but this definitely does the trick.

Comment: Yup... this error is really annoying sometimes. I agree with @hrbrmstr that you should report this bug on rvest github page.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just target the table better?

```
library(rvest)

wp_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Legislature,_2017%E2%80%9318_session"

leg <- read_html(wp_url)

html_node(leg, xpath=".//table[contains(., 'District')]") %>%
  html_table()
##            Position                   Position                   Name                  Party               District
## 1                          Lieutenant Governor           Gavin Newsom             Democratic                       
## 2                        President pro tempore          Kevin de León             Democratic       24th–Los Angeles
## 3                              Majority leader           Bill Monning             Democratic            17th–Carmel
## 4                                Majority whip          Nancy Skinner             Democratic           9th–Berkeley
## 5                        Majority caucus chair           Connie Leyva             Democratic             20th–Chino
## 6                   Majority caucus vice chair           Mike McGuire             Democratic         2nd–Healdsburg
## 7                              Minority leader         Patricia Bates             Republican     36th–Laguna Niguel
## 8                        Minority caucus chair            Jim Nielsen             Republican             4th–Gerber
## 9                                Minority whip             Ted Gaines             Republican    1st–El Dorado Hills
## 10        Secretary                  Secretary         Daniel Alvarez         Daniel Alvarez         Daniel Alvarez
## 11 Sergeant-at-Arms           Sergeant-at-Arms         Debbie Manning         Debbie Manning         Debbie Manning
## 12         Chaplain                   Chaplain Sister Michelle Gorman Sister Michelle Gorman Sister Michelle Gorman
```

ARGH! Wrong table. It's still unwise to just use numeric indexes like that. We can still target the table you want better:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

wp_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Legislature,_2017%E2%80%9318_session"

leg <- read_html(wp_url)

target_table <- html_node(leg, xpath=".//span[@id='Members']/../following-sibling::table")
```

But, `rvest::html_table()` is causing the error and you should absolutely file a bug report on the GH page for it.

The `htmltab` pkg in used in the other answer looks handy (and feel free to accept that answer vs this one since it's shorter and works).

We'll do it the old-fashioned way, but will need a helper function to make better column names:

```
mcga <- function(x) {
  x <- tolower(x)
  x <- gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+", "_", x)
  x <- gsub("_+", "_", x)
  x <- gsub("(^_|_$)", "", x)
  make.unique(x, sep = "_")
}
```

Now, we extract the header row and the data rows:

```
header_row <- html_node(target_table, xpath=".//tr[th]")
data_rows <- html_nodes(target_table, xpath=".//tr[td]")
```

We peek at the header row and see that there's an evil `colspan` in there. We'll make use of this knowledge later.

```
html_children(header_row)
## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <th scope="col" width="30" colspan="2">District</th>
## [2] <th scope="col" width="170">Name</th>
## [3] <th scope="col" width="70">Party</th>
## [4] <th scope="col" width="130">Residence</th>
## [5] <th scope="col" width="60">Term-limited?</th>
## [6] <th scope="col" width="370">Notes</th>
```

Get the column names, and make them tidy:

```
html_children(header_row) %>%
  html_text() %>%
  tolower() %>%
  mcga() -> col_names
```

Now, iterate over the rows, pull out the values, remove the extra first value and turn the whole thing into a data frame:

```
map_df(data_rows, ~{
  kid_txt <- html_children(.x) %>% html_text() 
  as.list(setNames(kid_txt[-1], col_names))
})
## # A tibble: 40 x 6
##    district              name      party       residence term_limited notes
##       <chr>             <chr>      <chr>           <chr>        <chr> <chr>
##  1        1        Ted Gaines Republican El Dorado Hills                   
##  2        2      Mike McGuire Democratic      Healdsburg                   
##  3        3         Bill Dodd Democratic            Napa                   
##  4        4       Jim Nielsen Republican          Gerber                   
##  5        5 Cathleen Galgiani Democratic        Stockton                   
##  6        6       Richard Pan Democratic      Sacramento                   
##  7        7      Steve Glazer Democratic          Orinda                   
##  8        8     Tom Berryhill Republican     Twain Harte          Yes      
##  9        9     Nancy Skinner Democratic        Berkeley                   
## 10       10    Bob Wieckowski Democratic         Fremont                   
## # ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But actually I was hoping to target the table beneath that one. And when I try to target that with, say, "...contains(., 'Residence')]..." I get the same error.

Comment: Updated (I kept the original up there tho)

Comment: Thanks very much! For the sake of simplicity, I think I'll go with Prem's work-around below, but I appreciate you putting so much thought into this.

Comment: I'd use Prem's as well IRL :-) Don't forget to file a bug report on the rvest GH! :-)