# Scrape multiple tables from Wikipedia in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I am trying to scrape content of this Wiki Page using rvest library in R

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2019)

I want to extract 4 tables which contains data wrt release of bollywood films in 2019 (January–March,April–June, July–September,October–December)

Already done

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2019"
webpage <- read_html(url)
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

#Then I match with the word opening & I get 4 tables as in wikipedia page, however I am struggling to combine them into one dataframe & store it 

tbls[grep("Opening",tbls,ignore.case = T)]
```

### This Gives error

```
df <- html_table(tbls[grep("Opening",tbls,ignore.case = T)],fill = T)
```

I understand because it returned multiple tables, I am missing something subscript somewhere not sure where. Help !

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585699/rvest-html-table-error-error-in-outj-k-subscript-out-of-bounds) seems helpful.

Comment: As indicated in that link and on page 8 of [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) for html_table there is the expectation: _No cells span multiple rows_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complicated HTML tables, I recommend `htmltab` package:

```
library(purrr)
library(htmltab)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2019"
tbls <- map2(url, 4:7, htmltab)
tbls <- do.call(rbind, tbls)
```

Comment: this works perfect just the name of the cast is not having delimiter between them, hence difficult to separate. Could you help on that ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way for you while I believe there are better ways to handle your case. When you use the `rvest` package, you can use SelectGadget. You see that there are 15 tables in the link. First, you want to scrape all tables and create a list object. Then, you want to subset the list with column information. The tables that you want to scrape have `Opening` as a column name. So I used a logical check to test if there is a column with that name in each of the list element and got the four tables that you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltab)

map(.x = 1:15,
    .f = function(mynum) {htmltab(doc = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2019",
                                  which = mynum, rm_nodata_cols = F)}) -> res

Filter(function(x) any(names(x) %in% "Opening"), res) -> out
```

Comment: Interesting +.  I  had a go at running this. With rvest you could have got just the right tables with html_nodes('.wikitable:not(.sortable)')    though that doesn't solve the overall problem.

Comment: @QHarr I was trying to use `wikitable` in `html_nodes()` as well and could not find any solution. So I was searching a workaround.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks. If you can think of any other ways, feel free to revise my suggestion here.

Comment: Lol. Nope. I went down a rabbit hole with htmlTable package

Comment: @QHarr I don’t know the package very well. I wanna learn it in 2020.